# How to configure Jquery autocomplete with jquery 1.6.2?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery latest version 1.6.2 but jQuery autocomplete was working fine with jQuery 1.2.6 version but it is not working with latest version(1.6.2). I am trying to bind my textbox in `document.ready()` function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input#account").autocomplete('<%= Url.Action("Find", "AccountSearch") %>');
});
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is the autocomplete plugin you are using compatible with jQuery 1.6.2? Going from 1.2.6 -> 1.6.2 looks like a big leap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery autoComplete has been deprecated. It has been moved to [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). Use that one instead.